# How do I break a program at N recursive call of a function?

Tags: c#, debugging, rider

I have a **recursive call** in my program:

```
Left?.Generate(ref result, ref resultGiven);
```

I want to debug my program and *stop execution* when this `Generate()` function was called **6** times. How do I do it?

Comment: Add a counter & exit when it gets to 6?

Comment: use Debugger.Launch() if counter = 6;

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a global var.

```
// somewhere before Generate first call
var counter = 0;

void Generate(ref result, ref resultGiven)
{
  if (counter == 6)
     return;
  counter++;
  // the rest of function's body
}
```

Comment: You are restricting *any* calls of the function: `Generate` can't be executed more than `6` times. However, it seems that OP wants to restrict the *depth* of the recursion (`Generate` must not *call itself* more than `6` times).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I cannot be sure but topic's name includes "break a program" words, so I think there are no difference between these cases.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, Oops, I just thought about "break a program" can mean not "stop execution" but "make a breakpoint". In this case your approach is preferrable, of cource.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you right, you want to restrict **depth** of the recursion (i.e. do not let `Generate` **call itself** more than `6` times). If it's your case, you can try [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) class for this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

void Generate(ref result, ref resultGiven) {
  // --- Comment this out after debugging
  string currentFrame = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(false)).ToString().Trim();

  StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();

  int depth = trace
    .ToString()
    .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(frame => frame.Trim() == currentFrame)
    //.TakeWhile(frame => frame.Trim() == currentFrame) // if direct calls only
    .Count();

  // Prevent Generate to call itself more than 6 time 
  if (depth > 6) {
    // Maximum depth reached, return or launch debugger - Debugger.Launch()
    return;  
  }
  // --- Comment this out after debugging

  ...
}
```

Comment: No... just no. Don't use reflection for something this simple.

Comment: That is the most demonic and genious use of reflection at the same time! Love it!

Comment: @riffnl: it's not *that simple*. What if `Generate` is called from different parts of the routine with different arguments? Let's aggravate: simultaneously from different *threads*?

Comment: so that's why you add a parameter (defaulting to 0 for instance : no need to adjust anything and threadsafe). Using reflection for this is using a sledgehammer to crack nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a count or step parameter would suffice;

```
Left?.Generate(ref result, ref resultGiven); // is same
```

And the function would look something like this:

```
void Generate(object ref result, object ref resultGiven, int step = 0)
{
  // do stuf

  // break for debug
  if (step >= 6)
  {
    return; 
  }
  // or only break when debugger is attached
  if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached && step >= 6)
  {
    return; 
  }
  // recursive
  Generate(ref result, ref resultGiven, step++);
}
```

Comment: It's not enough (in general case): suppose `Generate` calls method `Foo` which calls `Generate`. In your approach we have to change `Foo` as well.

Comment: True, but that is not (strictly speaking) recursion anymore.